# lstlistoflistings entry in table of contents name is always 'Contents'

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

I'm trying to add a list of code listings to my document, with a reference to it in the TOC. By simply calling

```
\lstlistoflistings
```

I end up getting everything I need (the list of listings, an entry in the TOC, etc) EXCEPT for the fact that the entry is always named 'Contents'. I was able to change the title of the listing page itself by running the command

```
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Code}
```

but this doesn't change the reference in the table of contents.

EDIT: Adding a minimal working example

```
\documentclass{Thesis}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Code}

\tableofcontents

\lstlistoflistings

\lstset{caption=Some Code}
\begin{lstlisting}
Some code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Add `\clearpage\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\lstlistlistingname}` just before `\lstlistoflistings`

Comment: @karlkoeller Could post an answer to this?

Comment: @Jubobs I'm not sure which `thesis.cls` the OP was using, so this can not be an answer.

Comment: @karlkoeller Then let's close it as *unclear what you're asking*.

Comment: @Jubobs I've added the answer anyway, since it should work in any case.

Comment: @karlkoeller Good call.

Comment: @Jubobs sorry, but closing this is as unclear is an overkill. The issue is the same regardless of the class, it's not something that would not appear as an issue in `article` and appear as one in a custom class. Voted for re-opening. As well, notice that nobody ever pointed out to the OP that usage of a custom class that we don't have is frowned upon.

Comment: @tohecz Ok, you're right.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: I vote to close this question as a duplicate of the recent question. The answer provided below does not work with the template.

Answer (score 13):

You see only "Contents" in the Table of Contents because that is the header of the ToC itself.

If you want to have an entry for your "List of Code", add the following lines

```
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\lstlistlistingname}
```

just before

```
\lstlistoflistings
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{Thesis}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Code}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\lstlistlistingname}

\lstlistoflistings

\lstset{caption=Some Code}
\begin{lstlisting}
Some code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]